# Upload video to facebook.com, Error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user - facebook-php-sdk v3.2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook-php-sdk-v3.2 to upload video from my website to a Facebook account.

This is my code:

```
<?php
 require 'src/facebook.php';
$file = "movie.mp4";
$post_type = '/me/videos';
$post_params = array(
'access_token' => '***************************',
'title' => 'title of the image',
'source' => '@' . $file,
);
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '1061864210567772',
'secret' => '***************************'
));
print  $facebook->getUser();
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); 
try{
$fbpost = $facebook->api($post_type, 'POST', $post_params);
print($fbpost);
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**This question is already asked before and I saw all of them**, but none of them worked for me. The output of this code is `0`

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

But the error is

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Comment: well, there is no user session. implement facebook login.

Comment: @luschn I am new to this thing. Would you please tell me how to do this? This is version `3.2` but the document in facebook website is for verion >4. The `$facebook ->getRedirectLoginHelper();` doesnt work

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login

Comment: not sure why people would use php for login, the js sdk is a lot easier to handle and did not change in the last few years.

Comment: _"I am new to this thing"_ - great, then you don't need to start using an outdated SDK. The documentation for the current PHP SDK v5 can be found here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted, and even provides explicit examples for video uploads.